# Generated MySQL 'AND' select behaving like 'OR' select

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm trying to build a MySQL search to match keywords occurring in any order in the column being searched (not just whole phrases as would normally be the case). My class function is:

```
    public function keywords_author($keywords, $author) {

        $keywords = explode(" ", trim($keywords));
        $keywords = array_filter($keywords);
        $count_keywords = count($keywords);

        if ($count_keywords != 0)  {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE ";
            $query_echo = $query;

            $a = 0;

            while ($a < $count_keywords) {
                $query .= "`column` LIKE :keyword ";
                $query_echo .= "`column` LIKE '%" . $keywords[$a] . "%' ";
                $a++;
                if ($a < $count_keywords) {
                    $query .=  " && ";
                    $query_echo .= " && ";
                }
            }

            $stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);

            for ($a=0; $a<$count_keywords; $a++) {
                $keyword = "%" . $keywords[$a] . "%";
                $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword);
            }

            $stmt->execute();

            $output = '';

            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               // build $output
            }            

            echo $output;
            echo $query_echo;
        }

    }
```

I have just added $query_echo to check the query being built, which is:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
WHERE `column` LIKE '%php%' 
&& title LIKE '%mysql%' 
&& title LIKE '%jquery%' 
&& title LIKE '%ajax%'
```

This works fine when I copy that into the SQL command line in phpMyAdmin, returning only those records where ALL keywords are matched, but when I run the class file in my site it behaves like an OR select and returns results where ANY of the keywords occurs in the column.

I'm confused! Any ideas what's going on would be a huge help!

David -

Thanks, David Kmenta - that's certainly a step in the right direction and now I'm getting the correct query:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE :keyword0 AND column LIKE :keyword1 AND column LIKE :keyword2 AND column LIKE :keyword3 AND column LIKE :keyword4

But it is still returning the result for the last value only. I am sure it is a basic, probably obvious error in the loop enclosing the new bindParam statement:

```
        for ($a=0; $a<$count_keywords; $a++) {
            $keyword = "%" . $keywords[$a] . "%";
            $stmt->bindParam(':keyword'.$a, $keyword);
        }
```

I'm very tired - can you spot the problem?
But

Comment: Use `AND` instead of `&&` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: That makes no difference. I have now found that it is returning the results for the last query keyword only and ignoring all the others.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is probably here:

```
for ($a=0; $a<$count_keywords; $a++) {
    $keyword = "%" . $keywords[$a] . "%";
    $stmt->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword);
}
```

Every occurrence of :keyword is replaced with last item in $keywords array.

Comment: I think you're right - by the time it gets to the bindParam, only the last variable is stored. It would be easy to solve this if not using a prepared statement, just by inserting the variables - but I want to avoid that. I'll have to think again.

Comment: You can use counter, so in `while` do something like this ``$query .= "`column` LIKE :keyword".$counter." ";`` and in `for` this `$stmt->bindParam(':keyword'.$a, $keyword);` :)

Comment: David - many thanks. I tried to reply but it was too long for the coment so I edited my question. It is still returning the last result only. Can you spot the problem in:

`        for ($a=0; $a<$count_keywords; $a++) {
            $keyword = "%" . $keywords[$a] . "%";
            $stmt->bindParam(':keyword'.$a, $keyword);
        }      `

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Done it - using:

            for ($a=0; $a<$count_keywords; $a++) {
                $keyword[$a] = "%" . $keywords[$a] . "%";
                $stmt->bindParam(':keyword'.$a, $keyword[$a]);
            }  

Thanks!